# How to find the grammar for a language where one symbol is not repeated as many times as the sum of the others?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am trying to find the grammar that generates the language

L = {a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>k</sup> | j ≠ i + k}

However, I am having a hard time to understand how to create a grammar that does this. I also cannot find information on the internet about dealing with inequalities in context free grammar.

My first thoughts are to split this up into:

L = {a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>k</sup> | j < i + k} **|** {a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>k</sup> | j > i + k}

Even hints or ideas you think might be obvious would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a good one - break it up into easier subproblems based on the disjunction in "not equal" and then join them:

```
S -> L | G
```

Now, how do we make a grammar to give a^i b^j c^k where j < i + k? We can start with a grammar where j = i + k. To do this, let's write it as a^i b^i b^k c^k. Then it becomes clear that this grammar works:

```
L -> BC
B -> aBb | e
C -> bCc | e
```

Now, how do we change this to enforce j < i + k? We must increase either i, or k, or both. We can add B -> aB and C -> Cc to allow more a and c, but not enforce it. We can enforce at least one of the two conditions by changing L -> BC to account for both possibilities (we could also add L -> aBCc for clarity but this is not necessary).

```
L -> aBC | BCc
B -> aBb | aB | e
C -> bCc | Cc | e
```

For G, we start the same way:

```
G -> DE
D -> aDb | e
E -> bEc | e
```

Now, we need to enforce the adding of extra b. We can do this by allowing more b the rules for D and E, and then requiring it in the rule for G:

```
G -> DbE
D -> aDb | Db | e
E -> bEc | bE | e
```

Combining these should give a grammar for the desired language:

```
S -> L | G
G -> DE
D -> aDb | e
E -> bEc | e
G -> DbE
D -> aDb | Db | e
E -> bEc | bE | e
```

Answer (score 0):

By solving for the two inequalities and then combining them into a single grammar I was able to solve this.

L = {a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>k</sup> | j > i + k} **|** {a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>k</sup> | j < i + k}

First {a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>k</sup> | j > i + k}:

Consider `^` to be the null symbol.

```
G -> aA  
A -> aA | aAc | B  
B -> aB | aBb | ^
```

Then {a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>k</sup> | j < i + k}

```
L -> Cc  
C -> Cc | aCc | D  
D -> Db | aDb | ^
```

And to combine them simply union the two:

```
S -> G | L
```

To derive simply sum j and k and then determine which path G or L to follow. I worked out a couple example derivations below:

[image]